# How to combine using and try/catch statements?

Tags: c#

Here is my method:

```
public BackgroundJobInfo Deserialize(string info)
{
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(info))
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlTextReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            return (BackgroundJobInfo)Serializer.ReadObject(xmlTextReader);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException(e, "Error when deserializing a BackgroundJobInfo object from string <{0}>", info);
             return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Where will I need to use `using()` statement? Maybe just inside `try {...}`?

Comment: Explain what you want this method to do... `new StringReader()` can throw, which will not be caught by your try-catch.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Everything working fine. But what is the common practice to use try catch and using? Some recommendation?

Comment: So there is no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your stringReader is not needed outside the try block I would suggest you use it this way:

```
public BackgroundJobInfo Deserialize(string info)
{        
        try
        {
          using (var stringReader = new StringReader(info))
          {
            var xmlTextReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
            return (BackgroundJobInfo)Serializer.ReadObject(xmlTextReader);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException(e, "Error when deserializing a BackgroundJobInfo object from string <{0}>", info);
             return null;
        }    
}
```

But at the end it is up to you to decide how you want to use it.